# get $post (object,parts/values) in meta-box

Tags: metabox

I want to know, how to get i.e. $post ID, TITLE and etc.. in metabox?

is other solution available, instead of `$GLOBALS['post']` ?

Comment: What happens if you try `get_the_ID()` or `get_the_title()`?

Comment: @czerspalace hm, you got it in bullet. however, i not only want those parts, an dont want to use separate functions, but want an object which contains `$post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not rely on globals like `get_the_ID()` or `get_post()` do. Use the parameters for your callbacks.

You get the current post object **twice**:

1. When you register the metabox, you get the post object as a second parameter.
2. When your output callback is called, you get it as the first parameter.

Here is an example showing both cases:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function( $post_type, \WP_Post $post ) {
    add_meta_box(
        'test', // handle
        'Box title', // title
        function( \WP_Post $post ) { // output
            print get_the_title( $post );
    });
});
```

Comment: that was what i was looking. So, it sends `$post` as parameter, right?

Comment: @TazoTodua Yes, it does. This is the only reliable source. During my support for MultilingualPress, I have seen other plugins messing up the global post object completely. This is very hard to debug and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: WP has something to invent to grow-up plugin developers... Or at least, they should be forced to follow some standards and guidelines... many many plugins are so poorly coded..

Answer (score 1):

Just go with what the API provides (the global `$post` object refers to the post that is set up via the main query loop `setup_postdata()` function):

```
$post = get_post( get_the_ID() );
```

All other API functions also refer to the `$_GLOBALS['post']` variable and the `global $wp_query` (and respectively the `global $wp_the_query`) vars. Just call `get_the_title()`, etc. and you are good. Sidenote: All this is cached per default, so repetitive calls do not hurt.

**Edit:** Drop what this answer provides and go with what @toscho wrote in his answer, which was correctly chosen as solution.